# Как переименовать раздел реестра?

Tags: windows, winapi, реестр

Нужно переименовать раздел реестра с `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\path1\` на `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\path2\`.
Хотелось бы не перебирать все значения и копировать их в новый раздел. Смотрел на функцию `RegCopyTree`, но она есть только начиная с Vista, нужно и для XP.
Как это лучше сделать средствами WINAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Windows 2000, XP аналогом функции RegCopyTree является функция [SHCopyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773482(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нашел;) Интересно, эту функцию оставили в Windows Vista/7?